# Accessing a data from a mongodb database where data is stored using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

My question is that is there is any chance of querying a data that is stored in mongodb atlas database from a JavaScript file using mongoose , in which data is sent from raspberry pi to a mongodb database using pymongo.

Comment: Sure. Can you narrow down your question to a specific problem you're having with it?

Comment: I am sending data from a raspberry pi using pymongo to the mongodb database and i want to query the same data by a file placed in a nodejs server using mongoose framework